# Scope of variable in different thread at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Consider the below code:

```
public void MyMethod()
    {
        bool flag=true;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (x, y) =>
            {
                //time consuming task
                if (flag)
                {
                    //do something
                }
            };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (x, y) =>
            {
                if (flag)
                {
                    //do something
                }
            };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Perhaps a stupid question, but as I can understand, after `runworkerasync` call, the `dowork` event is raised which runs its method on a different thread. Is checking the value of the local variable `flag` safe inside the `dowork` eventhandler since I feel the code exits `MyMethod` after calling `worker.RunWorkerAsync`?

Answer (score 4):

There's no problem with `flag` here because of a concept called [Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx). However, especially with threads this *can* be dangerous (use your favourite search engine).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of 'safe', it is possible to check the local variable `flag` within `DoWork` as it remains in scope for that method. Having said that it may not necessarily be thread safe.